# gnuplot - nonlinear curve fitting, parameter initialization and boundary definition

Tags: gnuplot, non-linear-regression

I'm trying NLCF in Gnuplot. My question is how to set bounds and initialize parameters for a function of the following form:

```
g (x) = k1*x**(0.5) + k2*x + a*(1-exp(-b*x));
```

I am looking for the values of "k1", "k2", "a" and "b" for the data:

```
x y
0 0
60 0.04959
300 0.1405
600 0.21488
900 0.27273
1200 0.35537
2400 0.59917
3000 0.72727
3600 0.82645
5400 0.92975
7200 0.97107
9000 0.98347
10800 0.9876
12600 0.9876
16200 0.9876
18000 1.02066
23400 1.00413
27000 1
```

Unfortunately, I got negative values which may not make sense. I have tried to set bounds for the parameters (i.e. k1, k2, a, b> 0), but I can't do that in Gnuplot.
Thanks for any help and tip.

Comment: Is there a typo in the third row from bottom? Shouldn't this number be 18000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To initialise the variables just define them before the fit. You should choose reasonable starting guesses for the fit to converge; I was getting a pretty decent result with the following guess:

```
k1=1e-9
k2=1e-9
a=1
b=5e-4
```

I plotted your data points and the function and kept trying out different starting values, until the function looked good, and then ran the fit.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. 
After initializing the parameters, the fit is very good indeed, unfortunately the values of parameters I am looking for (especially "k1", "k2" and "b") should be positive. Is it possible to establish this for additional condition during fit?

I got the following values:

    Final set of parameters            
    =======================            
    k1              = -0.00141587     
    k2              = 4.37053e-06      
    a               = 1.11483         
    b               = 0.000403388

Comment: In short: No, to my knowledge ranges for fit parameters are not available.
If you are getting nonphysical results your data might be bad, or your model might be overfitting or be unsuited.